# I can't close images from list using close() from pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I opened images with Image.open() and stored them in the 2d list "images". But now I'm trying to close all the images using close() function and the code compiles but it doesn't close the files

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    for j in range(len(images[i])):         
        print(images[i][j])
        images[i][j].close()

print(images)

output:
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4A6A280>
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4A6A3D0>
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DACCA0>
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB7430>
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB7610>
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB76A0>
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB7730>
[[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4A6A280>], [<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4A6A3D0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DACCA0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB7430>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB7610>], [<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB76A0>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1080x1080 at 0x7F9BD4DB7730>]]
```

Comment: [`Image.close()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.close) doesn't destroy the `Image` instance, it *will* close the associated file pointer if it can. The code in your question proves nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing an image makes it unusable from that point forward, but doesn't remove it from the list.  You would almost certainly get an error if you tried to actually do anything with those images.  Maybe after you close it, you should replace it with `None`:

```
images[i][j] = None
```

Comment: does list.clear() do the same?

Comment: @Eugene `list.clear()` will definitely get rid of all the images, but in a different way - the list will be empty.